# Can a co-op tenant shareholder exclude people from common areas if they refuse to abide by house rules?

Tags: tenant, trespass, new-york-city, public-health

In New York City, can a co-op tenant/shareholder refuse to allow a guest or contractor of another tenant/shareholder into common areas of the building if the person is violating the co-op's house rules by refusing to wear a mask in the common areas of the building?